# Iphone: images are rotated

Tags: iphone, wordpress, ipad

my website is responsive .  it is working fine . i found strange issue,

in ipad and iphone slider images looks rotated. in other words for iphone and ipad the image looks **90degree rotated** while for the desktop and other mobiles it looks perfect.

problem occurring in **ipad** and **iphone** only.

what could be the issue?

there is only 1 style sheet for my custom wordpress theme.

how to rectify this issue?

Comment: It is not clear how your website is connected with ipad/iphone images. By uploading from iDevice to you website?

Comment: my site is resposnive .   in other mobile phones images looks perfect while only for ipad and iphone the images looks rotated.  i google it but didn't find solution of it. while few days ago it was working without any issue in iphone and ipad..  have you ever found solution of such issues>?

Comment: Is there any url we can check with ?